# add_submenu_page() issue

Tags: wp-admin, add-submenu-page

I am trying to add a Menu in WordPress Admin Panel. I am using below code.

This code is working.

```
add_submenu_page('weather_info', 'Weather Information', 'Weathers', 'manage_options', 'weathers', [$this, 'weathers']);
```

But below code is not working. I am facing error `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'edit.php?post_type=weather' not found or invalid function name` .

```
add_submenu_page('weather_info', 'Weather Information', 'Weathers', 'manage_options', 'weathers', 'edit.php?post_type=weather');
```

Answer (score 1):

`edit.php?post_type=weather` isn't a valid PHP function name.

If you're trying to set the menu up as a submenu of your custom post screens, I think `edit.php?post_type=weather`—the `$parent_slug`—should be the first parameter, not the last. ie,

```
add_submenu_page(
  'edit.php?post_type=weather',
  'Weather Information',
  'Weathers',
  'manage_options',
  'weathers',
  [$this, 'weathers']
);
```

### References

- [`add_submenu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/)